# Remove color which is present on top of Radio buttons & add border color

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, background-color

We are using below code to add circular background for an image. once we click on image , its working fine [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html)

but along with image, its adding background color on top of radio buttons once we click on Radio buttons.

[image]

We are using same class for both Radio buttons and an image.

we dont want to display background color on top of **Radio buttons L , M , S ,XL , XXL**. Instead , we want to add `background color` for only border which covers Radio buttons.

**css**

```
.label {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.label label {
    margin-top: 4px !important;
}

.product-options .input-box ul.options-list .label>label.colors { 
margin-top: 4px !important; 
left: 0; 
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
}

.product-options ul.options-list .label { 
border: none !important; 
box-shadow: none !important; 
}
```

**html**

```
<span class= "label">
<label for="options_456_3">M </label>
</span>
```

**script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var inner = Array(); 
inner = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label"); 
for (i=0;i<inner.length;i++){ 
var classN = inner[i].innerText;  
if (classN=="Black" || classN=="Blue"|| classN=="Red"|| classN=="White"||) {  
classN = classN.toLowerCase(); 
var urlB = "http://stylebaby.com/media/catalog/custom/"+classN+".png"; 
inner.eq(i).css('background-image', 'url(' + urlB + ')'); 
} 
} 
});
```

I tried using **nth-child** as below code. but after that it removed background- color for image also.

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label:nth-child(2) {
    background: none;
}
```

please help me, i am new to css....

**Edit**

with help of below code, i removed color on top of Radio buttons, now  i need to add border color for Radio buttons - L, XL, M.....etc

```
#options-456-list > li > .label{
    background:transparent;
    }
    #options-454-list > li > .label{
    background:transparent;
    }
```

Comment: is you want add border color to sizes options like you add on colors option when user click on it

Comment: @arsh_kalsi thats absolutely right, all i wanted is to add border color only for boundary for L, M, XL .... as like below images......

Comment: join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/133852/yang-yin?tab=general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your css:

```
.product-options ul.options-list input[type="radio"]:checked + span label{
    border:2px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

credits : [frnt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5805150/frnt) for hiding color on top of Radio buttons

```
#options-456-list > li > .label{
    background:transparent;
    }
    #options-454-list > li > .label{
    background:transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique class name for these elements like "circular-bg-clr" to avoid conflict with Radio buttons L , M , S ,XL , XXL.

Something like this:

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label.circular-bg-clr { 
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: as we are not writing html code for  `L, M, S` statically, these values are coming dynamically using php, so i dont think we can add classes for all `L,M,S.....` , can you please help me with only css with existing classes.....

Comment: Right now your existing classes are not good enough to differentiate elements. You can use "#options-456-list" id to differentiate those elements as your current HTML structure like: ".product-options #options-455-list span.label".

Answer (score 0):

To remove orange border on top of L M XL

```
.options-list input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background: transparent; border:2px solid red;
}
```